# Auto Complete of html tags does not work with vue inertiajs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, autocomplete, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am using `inertia-vue` with Laravel, and the problem is that when I write an HTML tag inside the .vue files, no auto-complete work. Although I downloaded some extensions like vetur, vue 3 snippets, and vue-helper.

and this notification occurs to me

[image: Vetur can't find tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json]

So what can I do?

NOTE: auto-complete works in `.blade.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

create a file called 'tsconfig.json' inside the folder of your project and put this code inside:

```
{"compilerOptions": {"module": "commonjs",  "allowJs": true  },  "exclude": [   "node_modules"  ]}
```

Now vetur will find the file.